# Open in iBook a PDF with spaces in the name

Tags: ios, ipad

I've implemented the already nth-times discussed open in iBook feature in my PDF viewer. And it works great when the PDF file does not contain spaces (example1.pdf, example2.pdf). When the PDF has some space (example 1.pdf) in the name clicking the open in iBook button does nothing.

```
NSString *fileURL = [(Documents *)(self.detailItem) url];
NSArray *subStrings = [fileURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filePath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[subStrings lastObject]];
docIntController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
docIntController.delegate = self;
docIntController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";

[docIntController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
```

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you put `NSLog(@"%@", [subStrings lastObject]);` somewhere and tell us the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the filePath string is intended to be a URL, you likely need to run it through [`NSString -stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744) before invoking `fileURLWithPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the full path that you send to iBooks in quotes.
For example, use "example 1.pdf" instead of example1.pdf.

Comment: enclosing in quotes it does not open even the files without spaces